# Get listbox selected items based on observable collection

Tags: wpf, listbox, observablecollection, selecteditem

There is no error in this code but when it is executed objTextList is still null and doesn't get myListBox selected items.Why?

```
private void ButtonFill_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<TextList> objTextList = myListBox.SelectedItems as List<TextList>;
    if (objTextList == null)
        return;
    foreach(var item in objTextList)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(item.Id.ToString());
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(item.Text.ToString());
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(item.Name.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: not understood ur question !

Comment: updated.I just want to get selected items from myListBox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListBox.SelectedItems returns an `IList` not an `IList<TextList>` so the cast returns null. You can use the Linq extension method Cast to achieve your desired results.

```
List<TextList> objTextList = myListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<TextList>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add a comment, so I'll write here.

Please provide the `xaml` definition for `myListBox` too.

If you add this

```
foreach (var item in myListBox.SelectedItems)
    {
        var temp = item as TextList;
        MessageBox.Show(temp.Id.ToString());
        //and so on
    }
```

what would be the output?

Comment: Player.TextList is output

Comment: Then cast every item to `TextList`. Check my updated unswer! Your cast must be null, as @LeeO said.